# 18.10 qtpass not opening

Tags: command-line, permissions, password, 18.10, qt

QTpass does not open for my user from the menu or from the command line. From the command line the terminal simply returns the prompt.

The journal shows nothing.

I can run `pass` from the command line and manage the database that way so I assume there is not a problem there.

Permissions on the `.password-store` directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

Oddly, if I switch to a root session, the system opens the qtpass initialisation dialog. (sudo also fails)

I have re-installed. No effect.

*UPDATE*

Running with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 qtpass` gives the error `Cannot load library gtk-x11-2.0: (gtk-x11-2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)`. A number of google hits suggest this is `libgtk-x11-2.0` which is a 32-bit library. My system is 64-bit, and as I explain above, the application does work when run as root user in both my directory and in /root. (sudo does not have this effect)

Comment: Do you get any debug output if you run `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 qtpass`?

Comment: Many lines. I see one error near the end `Cannot load library gtk-x11-2.0: (gtk-x11-2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)` Is there anything else I should look for?